# Unable to use raw_input() during event handeling in Matplotlib while running pylab -- RuntimeError: can't re-enter readline

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I'm trying to write a script that allows the user to manipulate a graph via event handling in matplotlib, but I need to have them enter some additional information through the terminal

Calling `raw_input()` seems to break the scripts, and throws a `RuntimeError: can't re-enter readline` error

here's a simple piece of code to demonstrate this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

def keypress(event):
    print 'You press the "%s" key' %event.key
    print 'is this true? Type yes or no'
    y_or_n = raw_input()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', keypress)
plt.show()
```

This works fine if I run it using python, but breaks using ipython --pylab. Unfortunately, I need the interactive mode

I see other people have had this problem but I haven't seen a solution

Answer (score 3):

You're running into trouble because matplotlib is still listening for keypresses. Unfortunately, simply disconnecting its event listening did not work for me interactively. This solution, however,  did work. Though it limits you in not being able to use the 'y', 'e', 's', 'n', or 'o' keys. There are workarounds for this if that is a necessity.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#disable matplotlib keymaps
keyMaps = [key for key in plt.rcParams.keys() if 'keymap.' in key]
for keyMap in keyMaps:
    plt.rcParams[keyMap] = ''

str = ''

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

def keypress(event):
    global str

    if event.key in ['y','e','s','n','o']:
        str += event.key
    else:   
        print 'You press the "%s" key' %event.key
        print 'is this true? Type yes or no'

    if str == 'yes':
        print str
        str = ''
    elif str == 'no':
        print str
        str = ''

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', keypress)
plt.show()
```